# Hibernate distributing cache between multiple applications

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

Is it possible to distribute Java Hibernate cache between multiple applications without implementing some external infrastructure? I have separate hibernate context file in every application, maybe merging it into one somehow will do the trick. All apps are deployed on the same server (jboss).

Comment: hazelcast or ehcache can provide this kind of feature

Comment: What is Java Hibernate cache?

Answer (score -1):

Cacheonix provides a distributed Hibernate cache plugin: https://github.com/cacheonix/cacheonix-core